# typescript spread operator for props in react throw error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When using typescript with react, I want to skip passing every single props especially native props for HTML like id, name, placeholder etc but I got error on my `{...props}`

I've extended my interface with `InputHTMLAttributes` so that typescript didn't check my props but it still got unresolved error

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface MyComponentProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  nonNativeProp: string;
  props: object
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({
  nonNativeProp,
  props
}) => {
  return <input type="text" {..props} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent
        nonNativeProp="abc"
        placeholder="Name"
        name="something"
        id="myInput"
        data-custom="custom-attr"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-forest-42t4b?file=/App.tsx

Comment: Probably a typho.. you should have 3 dots and not 2 dots in the spread operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to use rest spread syntax to get props and not destructure like an object

Secondly interface needn't define props as an object

Lastly you have `{..props}` instead of `{...props}`. Notice 3 dots before props

```
interface MyComponentProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
  nonNativeProp: string;
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps> = ({
  nonNativeProp,
  ...props
}) => {
  return <input type="text" {...props} />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyComponent
        nonNativeProp="abc"
        placeholder="Name"
        name="something"
        id="myInput"
        data-custom="custom-attr"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-leavitt-ro119?file=/App.tsx)

Comment: you said interface need to define prop as object, but I didn't see any warning when you leave it empty?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part which completely changed the meaning. What I meant was interface need not define props as an object. Updated the post